# CPU load is almost 100%, during startup Python interpeter

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

After I left my script to work at night, on the morning of Python environment (2.7) took one hundred percent of CPU resources even without running scripts. Tell me please, what could be the problem and seek a solution which side?

Comment: Have you tried `top` to figure out which process used up your cpu?

Comment: Yes. It's only a python environment.

Comment: What is that *Python environment* you talk about that is unrelated to running scripts?

Comment: Maybe I did not use those terms. I mean Рython process running under GNU / Linux from the terminal (without having to run the script - "sudo python"). After I did run  the Python in terminal, it takes a 100% CPU.

Comment: Maybe you should paste the `top`'s output here.

Comment: It must be running something!

Comment: Unfortunately, I put a clean system on my Raspberry, so I can not paste the results "top" here. 

I sad about Python interpeter in my proceses. I apologize for such a complex explanation of my problem and I am grateful that you are trying to help me.

Comment: You can try running `python` as `strace python` so you'd see which commands are being executed. Note: `strace`does not follow symlinks - so give python's full path if you get _error 2._

Comment: Thank you, boardride. I'll try it to solve my problem. If anything I find, framed here as a response.

Comment: Why  change `python` environment ? A lot of service run with python. Maybe some service fighting for finished job ! Reinstall pi os. don't waste your time.

Comment: @dsgdfg what some people call 'wasting time' others call 'learning'